# PowerShell: Delete similar lines from file

Tags: regex, powershell, text-manipulation

Consider the file `tbl.txt` (**1.5 million lines**), built like:

`Num1 ; Num2 ; 'Value' ; 'Attribute'`

So `tbl.txt` looks like:

```
  63 ; 193 ; 'Green'  ; 'Color'
 152 ; 162 ; 'Tall'   ; 'Size'
 230 ; 164 ; '130lbs' ; 'Weight'
 249 ; 175 ; 'Green'  ; 'Color'      *duplicate on 'Value' and 'Attribute'*
 420 ; 178 ; '8'      ; 'Shoesize'
 438 ; 172 ; 'Tall'   ; 'Size'       *duplicate on 'Value' and 'Attribute'*
```

How can i keept the first unique line on `'Value'` and  `'Attribute'` 
and delete following duplicate lines on `'Value'` and  `'Attribute'` ?

The result should look like:

```
  63 ; 193 ; 'Green'  ; 'Color'
 152 ; 162 ; 'Tall'   ; 'Size'
 230 ; 164 ; '130lbs' ; 'Weight'
 420 ; 178 ; '8'      ; 'Shoesize'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Comment: Use the search box above and take a look at some of the existing questions about unique values, they should help point you in the right direction. Like this one: [Powershell - filtering for unique values](//stackoverflow.com/q/9825060)

Comment: Initially I was looking to modifying `cat tbl.txt | Get-Unique` accordingly but didn't find a solution.
@James I can't see yet how  I can turn `Foreach-Object { $_.Substring(0,2) } | 
  Select-Object -unique` into a proper solution as the length of the line varies.

Comment: How can I modify
`cat tbl.txt | Group { $_.Substring(10,15) } | select Name | sort-object -Property Name -Unique
  Select-Object -unique`

So that the Value of Group is returned?

Comment: I'll point you in the direction of `Import-CSV`, with the Delimiter & Header params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the text-file via `Get-Content`, separate the columns `'Value' ; 'Attribute'` through string operations, and then use a hashmap in order to check whether you already processed a similar line -- if not, output the line once. In code:

```
$map = @{};
Get-Content tbl.txt | ` 
             %{ $key = $_.Substring($_.IndexOf(';',$_.IndexOf(';')+1)+1); `
                If(-not $map.ContainsKey($key)) { $_; $map[$key] = 1 } `
              }
```

Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, you can use `group` and apply the same substring as grouping criterium, and finally take the first element of each group:

```
Get-Content tbl.txt | group {$_.Substring($_.IndexOf(';',$_.IndexOf(';')+1)+1)} `
                    | %{$_.Group[0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data is without headers:

```
Import-CSV "C:\folder\data.txt" –Delimiter ";" -Header Num1,Num2,Value,Attribute | Sort-Object -Property Value -Unique
```

Gives your desired output:

```
Num1 Num2 Value     Attribute 
---- ---- -----     --------- 
230  164  '130lbs'  'Weight'
420  178  '8'       'Shoesize'
63   193  'Green'   'Color'
152  162  'Tall'    'Size'
```

You can use Export-CSV to export your results:

```
Import-CSV "C:\folder\data.txt" –Delimiter ";" -Header Num1,Num2,Value,Attribute | Sort-Object -Property Value -Unique | Export-CSV "C:\folder\data2.txt" –Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```